# How can i do this question putting the value 0 on the subsequent values/ logic

Tags: java, eclipse, vector

Hey can somebody help me on this code? Im did just the first part but i dont know how can i do the exercise, i dont know the logic. obs: im doing the code in portuguese

**12- Read a vector of 50-position integers and compress it, that is, eliminate the zero-valued positions by advancing one position, with the subsequent values ​​of the vector. In this way all “zeros” must go to the final positions of the vector.**

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int v[]=new int[5];

    for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Digite um valor");
        v[i]=s.nextInt();
        
        if(v[i]==0){
            v[i+1]=v[i];
        }
        if(v[i]==0 && i==(v.length-1)){
            v[i]=v[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
        System.out.println(v[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this function:

```
    if(v[i]==0){
        v[i+1]=v[i];
    }
    if(v[i]==0 && i==(v.length-1)){
        v[i]=v[i];
    }
```

You are assigning next position of the vector to the current position, so the next position will be lost forever, I'm guessing this will lead to value 0 in all positions since first encountered 0.

Might you try something like this?:

```
    if(v[i]==0){
        int nextValue = v[i+1];
        v[i+1]=v[i];
        v[i] = nextValue;
    }
    // This statement does not make sense, you can skip it and iterate until last - 1 index (**for(int i=0;i<v.length - 1;i++)**)
    // if(v[i]==0 && i==(v.length-1)){
    //    v[i]=v[i];
    // }
```

Also, now that I see, you does not have the next value stored when you are executing this peace of function, so it will not work as expected,
try defining first the values:

```
int v[]=new int[5];

for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Digite um valor");
    v[i]=s.nextInt();
}

// the solution here
```

Comment: I did what you told me but its not working   ` int v[]={1,2,0,4,5};
        int aux=0;
        int prox=0;
        for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
             if(v[i]==0){
                prox=v[i+1];
                v[i+1]=v[i];
                v[i]= prox;
            }
        }
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
            System.out.println(v[i]);
        }`

Comment: You should give a little more information about why this is not working :).
I can see that you forgot "v.length - 1" in the condition of the for loop, is this a IndexOutOfBoundsException?